# C# Lambda Entity Framework: Any way to use a predicate Lambda to choose records by row number?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I want to do paging outside of my Repository, but the Repository returns IList.  Since I don't want to pull data unnecessarily, and don't want to create specific Paging methods in my Repositories, **Is there any way to filter records by page in the Where extension method?**

I want to do something like:

```
var myRecords = ProductRepo.Get( p => p.Name.StartsWith("Pepsi") &&
                                      p.Row_Number() > 9 &&
                                      p.Row_Number() < 21);
```

The Get repository code (doesn't handle row number of course):

```
public IList<Product> Get( Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter = null)
{
    if( filter == null)
        return _dc.Products.ToList<Product>();
    else
        return _dc.Products.Where(filter).ToList<Product>();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of `ProductRepo.Get`?

Comment: Apparently this can only be done with not returning a Collection type from the repository, or doing the Skip and Take within the repository.  I wonder why you couldn't create a field within the SQL that represented ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY ).  I will keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

Return **IQueryable** from your **Repository** (don't call .ToList()). You will be able to use **Skip** and **Take** then.

ROWNUM is not supported in EF.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/055911ff-6db6-48cb-8e50-bd6415b7eefe/

Comment: :)  Lets say that the Repository returning IList is part of the requirement.  I know SQL server has a ROW_NUMBER() function.  I was just curious how we could add that to the where clause?

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```
var myRecords = ProductRepo.Get( p => p.Name.StartsWith("Pepsi") ).Skip(9).Take(12);
```

Comment: The problem is that .Get retrieves all the records in to a List.  .Skip and .Take would filter the already retrieved records.  If it's done in the Where clause, the skipped records would never leave the database.

Comment: Do not cast it to List within the function without take & skip.

Comment: That's really the root of the problem.  Given that you return an IList and that you don't have Take and Skip in the Repository, how could you achieve the same effect?

Comment: select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as row, * from Table.  Any way to get this in EF?  I could use it on the where statement then (p => p.row >9 && p.row < 21)